# How do I programatically remove an application from a Windows Mobile device?

Tags: deployment, windows-mobile

We've recently updated a Windows Mobile app and I want to create a utility that will:

1. remove the old version from the device
2. install the .NET Compact Framework
3. install the new app

Steps 2 and 3 seem simple enough, but I don't know about 1.  Is it possible?  If so, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Every time I've tried installing an application that is already on the phone, the OS tells you it's going to remove the currently installed version first (as long as the company name / application name remain the same).

So by doing #3 it should automatically do #1.

This is on my WM 6.1 phone.

Comment: This happens on all versions of WM.